# Vowpal Wabbit doesn't save the model despite -f flag is present

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit, hyperparameters

I encountered the following unexplainable behaviour in Vowpal Wabbit. Sometimes it simply doesn't save a model when `-f` flag is specified, without raising any exceptions.

The command is composed automatically by a script and has the following form (file names are changed):

```
vw -d ./data/train_set -p ./predictions
-f ./model --cache --passes 3 
--ftrl_alpha 0.106920149657 --ignore T -l 0.83184072971 
-b 29 --loss_function logistic --ftrl_beta 0.97391780827 
--ftrl -q SE -q SZ -q DR
```

Then it trains normally and the standard diagnostic information is displayed. But **the model is not saved**!

The most weird thing about it is that everything works fine with another parameter configurations!

The context: I'm working on hyperparameter optimization and my script successively composes `vw` training and validation commands. It always succeeds to get to 5th iteration, and always fails on the 6th (on exactly the same command). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you can come up with a minimal reproducible example (including the data file) please report it as an issue on github.  To make it minimal, please try to eliminate unnecessary options: e.g. `--power_t 0.5` is a no-op (since it is the default), so are `--l1 0` and `--l2 0`, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in Vowpal Wabbit source code. Now it's fixed and models are saved as expected. Here is an issue on Github:
https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/859